# Обновить или добавить в базу запись

Tags: php, mysql

Здравствуйте. В базе данных есть таблица `prom_item`

> id  - AUTO_INCREMENT
>
> trip - INT
>
> name - varchar **уникальный**
>
> date - varchar

Пытаюсь сделать чтобы если в базе уже есть запись, которая совпадает со значением ячейки **name** , и это поле отредактировано, то нужно чтобы в базе эта строка обновилась, а если нету - создается новая запись.

На сервере:

```
foreach ($_POST['prpunkt'] as $k => $f) {
    $namepp = $_POST['prpunkt'][$k];
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `prom_item` (`trip`, `name`) values('$nw_id', '$namepp')
     ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE name='$namepp')");
}
```

В итоге выходит что если я изменяю запись, (значение $_POST['prpunkt'][$k] ), строка в базе не обновляется, а записывается новая, и старая остается.

что я упускаю?

Comment: Так не name в UPDATE надо менять, а trip.

Comment: @Visman `trip` - это id статьи к которой привязываю доп поля. при чем это тут то?

Comment: Значит вы уникальный ключ не на то поле повесили. Раз вам нужно обновлять name у уникальной статьи с номером из trip, то уникальный ключ должен на trip быть, а не на name.

Comment: @Visman статьи в отдельной таблице хранятся. а доп. поля в таблице `prom_item` - доп полей может быть неопределенное кол-во у каждой статьи. то есть, значения **trip** - id статьи, к которой привязано это поле, не может быть уникальным уже.

Comment: Видимо вам не подойдет запрос вида `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, так как вы изменяете именно поле с уникальным ключем, а не сопутствующие ему поля.

Comment: ну, если у вас не highload, и грязное решение устроит (т.е. если просто надо чтобы хоть как-то заработало), то запросите кол-во записей с заданным name отдельным вопросом, и обновляйте/вставляйте данные в зависимости от результата... но повторюсь - это именно если устроит "абы как", для больших нагрузок это не правильно...

Comment: хотя, чем дальше залезаю под капот популярным движкам - тем больше понимаю, что почти все в этом мире делалось "абы как" :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут есть несколько вариантов.

**1) Вложенные запросы.** Так как вам надо сначало спросить - "А есть ли какое-то заначение в базе?", и если его нет - записать записать.
Пример:

**Данные которые сейчас в таблице:**

`SELECT * FROM user;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | name   | phone     |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | John   | 123123123 |
+----+--------+-----------+`

**Пытаемся записать что-то что уже есть в таблице:**

`INSERT INTO user (name, phone)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'John', '123123123') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM user WHERE name = 'John'
) LIMIT 1;`


`SELECT * FROM user;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | name   | phone     |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | John   | 123123123 |
+----+--------+-----------+`

**Пытаемся записать что-то, чего еще нет в таблице:**

`INSERT INTO user (name, phone)
SELECT * FROM (SELECT 'Bill', '111222333') AS tmp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT name FROM user WHERE name = 'Bill'
) LIMIT 1;`


`SELECT * FROM user;
+----+--------+-----------+
| id | name   | phone     |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  1 | John   | 123123123 |
+----+--------+-----------+
|  2 | Bill   | 111222333 |
+----+--------+-----------+`

**2) ON DUPLICATE.** Так как в mysql нет upsert, то можно еще копнуть в сторону ["ON DUPLICATE"](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).